# Geocoding with MMQGIS. How to use Google API Key?

Tags: qgis, geocoding, google-maps-api, api, mmqgis

I'm trying to geocode two csv files with 10 addresses each. When I tried with the first one, every address was located by Google, but when geocoding the second file I get this error:

*Exceeded Daily Google Limit: 0 addresses geocoded*

I got a Google API Key for geocoding and even after using this key, I still get the same error. These are the keys I got from Google

[image: api keys example]

- are these API keys the ones that I need?
- If so, why does MMQGIS say that I've exceeded my daily limit?
- Is there another way to geocode in QGIS?

Comment: You could spin up a CARTO account, geocode your data, and export it back to CSV/Shapefile. But I'm not sure why you're getting that error...

Answer (score 2):

Is there another way to geocode in QGIS?
with MMQGIS you can change the webservice to Nominatim .
[image: OSM Nominatim geocode service]

No more need an API key, but please have a look to the [policies](https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim/)

Comment: "No limit" is incorrect, there's a usage policy you have to adhere to, ref.: https://operations.osmfoundation.org/policies/nominatim

Comment: I was thinking about that. I mean No Number limit. Obliviously, as @mmd said, there is some requierement to respect. But in you case, 10 adresses will not be a problem.

Comment: Well, the OSM geocoder does geocode but it's not as efficient as the one from google. I think it's an alternative, but it's not the best one.